# Non-Negative Matrix Factorization - IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Tags: python, machine-learning, topic-modeling, nmf

Here is a piece of the dataset I will be using:

```
 u'tff prep normalized clean water permability ncwp result outside operating range',
 u'technician inadvertently omitted documenting initial room \u201c cleaned sanitized field form',
 u'sunflower seed observed floor room 1',
```

And here is the code I am using:

```
tfidf_model = vectorizer.fit_transform(input_document_lower)
tfidf_feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
nmf = NMF(n_components=no_topics, random_state=1, alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5, init='nndsvd').fit(tfidf_model)
```

Like the title states, I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

I'm honestly not sure how to start debugging this. I built an LDA using the the same dataset and had no issues. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide the FULL code, with input_document_lower, vectorizer, and no_topics explicitly defined. THIS (https://pastebin.com/JUM0dquy) code works for me okay.

Answer (score 5):

I think n_components should be less than (tfidf_model.shape[0], tfidf_model[1]).

Comment: Please post complete code (answer) instead of posting instead of single line comment.

Comment: To improve this answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

as Yotaro said, n_components need to be same or less than no_topics

> no_topics, words = tfidf_model.shape
>
> nmf = NMF(n_components=no_topics, random_state=1, alpha=.1,
>   l1_ratio=.5,init='nndsvd').fit(tfidf_model)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the no_topics variable to the x co-ordinate of tfidf_model.shape